# .net 4.5 ASP.Net web API JSONP support

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

Does anyone know if returning `JSONP` is supported out of the box in .net 4.5 ASP.NET WEB API?

I've found plenty of "roll your own" for earlier versions of `MVC` or .net but there doesn't seem to be anything specific to later versions.

I realize this could be because they earlier versions will work with .net 4.5 stack but I'm curious if someone has already been baked in.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know you must get the jsonp formatter. 
Here is one of the implementations:

<s>http://nuget.org/packages/WebApi.JsonP</s>

**UPDATE**

The recommended package is provided now by WebApiContrib team:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp

Add it to Global.asax on application start:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0,  new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));
```

Example of usage with jquery can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318144/correct-web-api-controller-action-method-definition-for-jsonp-request)

Comment: Thanks I was having the same issue this resolved it.  I see around the internet jsonp is a little light on documentation compared to JSON.  Are there any links besides the one found in your post that you've found good for implementation?

Comment: JSONP is actually a JSON object but it is wrapped in a Javascript function call specified by the client (the callback parameter). I don't think any documentation for it is neccessary. It just works using the formatter and any jsonp aware javascript library (like jQuery). I found a Stackoverflow post of someone explaining it in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about. Also updated my answer with the new recommended package as of now.

Answer (score 3):

This was the first post I found and was the most helpful but it still left a a few questions and I found a few problems with some of the answers, while I was able to make it work because of all the answers, I wanted to add what I learned because it seem to be high in the search returns.
I installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp and was able to get it to work after I added

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0,  new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));
```

to my Global.asax on application startas Alex Wheat and mbudnik answered, it caused the CORS to stop working on the other parts of my API that have all ready been implemented.

I now have it all working properly and figured out a few things from the package developer's github.

after installing the nuget package, 
Add the following to your Global.asax file

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.AddJsonpFormatter();
```

then if you call the service using the below Jquery, just replace the url with your url and you can see the results in you console. I also recommend getting Fiddler Web Debugger installed because it will help you troubleshoot.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
   type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'text/javascript',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,status,error) {
    console.log(error);
    }
});
```

The **contentType: 'text/javascript'** is important. This is what tells the web api to use the Jsonp Formatter.

Do not include a dataType of 'jsonp' - Example below

```
     ...type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,...
```

this will cause the web api to use the JsonMediaTypeFormatter and you will get the "jQuery*randomfunctionstring* was not called parsererror" error. I know this from personal trial and error. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I like this [WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp/) NuGet package

Add this formatter into `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ended up using the WebApiContrib.Formating.Jsonp NuGet Package, but keeping the ability to retun Json without padding if no callback parameter.

So only Jsonp IF the callback parameter i provided.

By adding (from the howTo) to Global.asax.cs - Application_Start()

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.AddJsonpFormatter();
```